Optimizing a complex pyspark join
I have a complex join that I'm trying to optimize.
df1 has columns id, main_key, col1, col1_isnull, col2,col2_isnull ... col30
df2 has columns id, main_key, col1, col2 ... col_30
I'm trying to run this sql query on Pyspark
select df1.id, df2.id
from df1 join df2
on df1.main_key = df2.main_key
AND (df1.col1_is_null OR (df1.col1 = df2.col1))
AND (df1.col2_is_null OR (df1.col2 = df2.col2)) ...

This query takes a very lot of time with just a few long running straggler tasks
both dataframes are huge, and the join key is skewed
Things I've tried:

I've enabled
spark.conf.set("spark.sql.adaptive.enabled", "true")
spark.conf.set("spark.sql.adaptive.skewJoin.enabled", "true")

Salting the smaller df, exploding the other

broadcasting the smaller df (sometimes the AQE overrides it with a SortMergeJoin(skew=true))

Filtering just the top 2 most common main_key value first, then doing all the above

Splitting the query to joining on main_key and then filtering using a 2nd query


The tasks execution still is very skewed
What more can I do to optimize this further?

Ensure the data is well-partitioned. Repartition df1 and df2 based on the main_key
df1 = df1.repartition(200, "main_key")  # Adjust the number of 
partitions based on your cluster size
df2 = df2.repartition(200, "main_key")


When dealing with skewed data and large datasets, requires a combination of techniques.
I name few. The one I am highlighting are extra suggestions on what you did not try yet.:

Dynamic partition pruning: Use broadcast join only for non-skewed keys. For skewed keys, partition data to ensure better distribution.
Salting with a variation: Using a secondary key in addition to the main_key to generate a more evenly distributed join.
Explicit bucketing
Filter irrelevant data before joining
Broadcast joins for specific conditions

so on and so forth ...
